# PHP Session in different folder

Tags: php

Problem PHP session in different folder.

I have problem with PHP session.

There are two folder: A AND B When I already logged in Folder A then i click link access to folder B when come to index.php file in Folder A. It doesn't to recognize session state.

PHP Code:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))
{   
    session_cache_expire (21900);
    $cache_expire = session_cache_expire();  
    session_start();
}
```

How can i check session redirect ?

```
f(!isset($_SESSION['a'])){
    redirce to a
}

f(!isset($_SESSION['b'])){
    redirce to b
}
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if(!session_id()) {
    session_start();
    session_cache_expire (21900);
}
```

Comment: How can i check session redirect ?

f(!isset($_SESSION['a'])){
    redirce to a
}

f(!isset($_SESSION['b'])){
    redirce to b
}

Answer (score 1):

Check your phpinfo() and look for suhosin.
If it is installed then you should disable it in order to let sessions be shared betwen different paths.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the validity scope of the PHPSESSIONID cookie is restricted to the folder `A`, so in folder `B` it doesn't get fed the same cookies. You have to change that to the parent folder containing both `A` and `B`.